# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-functions

Tags: python, windows, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have been doing this exercise:

#### **Create a function in Azure using Visual Studio Code**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-python

After doing the following steps:

- Select a language for your function project: Choose Python.
- Select a Python alias to create a virtual environment: Choose the location of your Python interpreter. If the location isn't shown, type in the full path to your Python binary.
- Select a template for your project's first function: Choose HTTP trigger.
- Provide a function name: Type HttpExample.
- Authorization level: Choose Anonymous, which enables anyone to call your function endpoint. To learn about authorization level, see Authorization keys.
- Select how you would like to open your project: Choose Add to workspace.

---

I press **F5** to **Run the function locally**

And this is the error I get:

[image]

I have python, pip, wheel, azure-function tools installed

```
PS C:\Users\Mustafa Saifee\azfunc> python --version
Python 3.8.2

PS C:\Users\Mustafa Saifee\azfunc> pip --version
pip 20.1 from c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

PS C:\Users\Mustafa Saifee\azfunc> wheel version
wheel 0.34.2

PS C:\Users\Mustafa Saifee\azfunc> pip install azure-functions 
Requirement already satisfied: azure-functions in c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages (1.2.1)
```

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Education 10.0.19041 Build 19041

#### How do I get this problem solved? Please help

Tried this as well:

> I tried python 3.7 and 3.8
>   plus I also tried it with the conda based python.
>   Then I uninstalled everything. And one by one installed it back. Still the issue persists

### I just want that error gone so that I can complete the rest of the exercise.

(I have posted this issue on my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/saifeemustafaq/azurefunctions/issues/1) as well if incase you can tag someone from the #azure-functions team on my [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/saifeemustafaq/azurefunctions/issues/1))

Comment: try `pip install azure-functions --force-reinstall` once and also you might wanna look at that SSL warning too.

Comment: I tried your steps, but didn't reproduce your issue. I am using pyhon3.7

Answer (score 1):

[@aprilspeight](https://github.com/aprilspeight) helped me solve this issue. So this issue can be closed.

> The solution is given by [@aprilspeight](https://github.com/aprilspeight): Have you tried running
>   the function while the init.py file is active on the screen?
>
> There shouldn't be a need to modify anything in the function.json file
>   if you're trying out the Quickstart. Therefore, ensure that you're
>   looking at the init.py file when you Start Debugging (F5).

The whole issue can be read [HERE](https://github.com/saifeemustafaq/azurefunctions/issues/1)